# how to integrate facebook like button for dynamic content javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbml, xfbml

I want to add a facebook like button to every individual post retrieved from the facebook fql stream from a person's news feed. So the href is dynamic, changes all the time, I have tried 3 ways to implement this;

**(1)** when I include the following in my html file, it brings up just the like button, but it's not related to that particualar post. obviously as href is empty.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="false" data-width="250" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

**(2)** I included the following div in my html

```
<div id=fblikebutton></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
fblikebutton_markup += '<div class="fb-like" data-href="'+post_href+'" data-send="false" data-width="250" data-show-faces="true"></div>';
$('#fblikebutton').empty().append(fblikebutton_markup);
```

post_href is the href for the current post, I am retrieving the correct href. But the above does not display anything.

**(3)** The following code brings up this error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

html:

```
<div id ="fblikebutton"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 fblikebutton_markup= '<fb:like href="'+post_href+'" send="false" width="250" show_faces="true"></fb:like>'
 $('#fblikebutton').append(fblikebutton_markup);
 FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikebutton'));
```

please help! I have looked around stack overflow but nothing is helping.

I now have a 4th try which still brings up the protocols must match error:

**(4)**
    jQuery("#fblikeblock").html('');
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));

Now having the 4th method, the button has disappeared! it doesn't work.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have appended the fb-like content into a container such as `$('.container')` then run   `FB.XFBML.parse($('.container')[0])` or   `FB.XFBML.parse($('.container'))`.

I have it implemented in a project that I have previously done.

Edited: Also make sure that the FB js is included in the page prior to your javascript FB.XFBML.parse being called.

Comment: Thanks that works, However when the like button is clicked I am given with the following error so the current post cannot be liked. "Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out why it is, it is because I am trying to like an object inside facebook in itself, the url is not just any website, I need to use something like  $('.fb-like').click(function() {
               FB.api('/'+postID+'/likes', 'post',function(response) {
    if(response === true) {
        alert("done!");
    }
});